# Sorting mysql columns (php)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Im trying to make a sort button for a table in php using data from a mysql table. My question is, Do you have to sort the mysql column directly using an ORDER BY query or can you sort the output of the MYSQL data so that it sorts the displayed data without effecting the mysql column?

Here's my code so far that's not doing anything.

```
if (isset($_POST['sort_torrent'])) {

      try{
    $sort_query = "SELECT movie_name FROM torrent_list ORDER BY 
movie_name";

    $db->query($sort_query);
}
catch (exception $e) {
    echo 'Error!' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't affect the columns in the table. It only affects the result/output from the query.

Comment: The result is just an array. You can sort the array anyway you like. Even after you output to html , you can still sort the result anyway you like, using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have to sort the mysql column directly using an ORDER BY query **OR** can you sort the output of the MYSQL data so that it sorts the displayed data without effecting the mysql column?

Not sure on your question, however, I will try.

The SQL Statement you have there will not affect the data in the **database**, you have just called the data from the database, then you ordered it in that instance or you could look at it like a copy of the data from the database, now you can do whatever you like with it and not affect your raw data.

When you use **INSERT** OR **UPDATE** Etc that will change the data in your database.